# Excel taking 30+ seconds to open any file on a network share

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

1 client of ours is having this issue where any file opened in excel, over the network will take 30-60 seconds to open

This issue has been troubleshot for over 20 hours now, so if I miss listing some of the troubleshooting steps I have already taken, forgive me.

This is the latest version of Office downloadable from O365. 32 and 64 bit versions both have the issue

It is ONLY excel, not word, not access, not outlook, EXCEL ONLY

Any excel type, xls, csv, xlsm, ect...

Files of any size, new or old. A test file with only 1 cell filled out also had this issue.

ONLY on windows 10. They have both a win 7 machine and a win 8 machine that do not have this issue, and 2 win 10 machines that both have this issue.

File verification has been disabled, AV has been disabled, no internal firewalls are present.

Cortana has been disabled

Dell Waves MaxxAudio is not present

Excel in safe mode has the same issue

Set EnableShellDataCaching to 1

Opening excel first and then a file, vs opening the excel file directly has no change. Also After a network file has been opened, any subsequent network files are still slow to open

Comment: Tried disabling Corona? ;) so all your clients have this isue if they are running win10 + office 365 (the latest download/version). And the problem only applies to the Excel application. Using Word or any programm outside of the office suite works fine, right?

Comment: With Process Monitor, can you capture a .PML log, containing all events, including the System process while you reproduce this?

Comment: Try in registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters` to create three DWORD items with the value of zero: `DirectoryCacheLifetime`, `FileInfoCacheLifetime` and `FileNotFoundCacheLifetime`. The source Microsoft [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)) about it is old, but may still apply.

Comment: @harrymc FYI (not sure if you noticed), the problem is Excel exclusive. As fas as I understand SMB2 is implemented on a "lower level" and therefore shouldn't effect just one application but all trying to access network files (if it even applies at all within this setting). But I'm still curious is the a specific reason why you suspect SMB2?

Comment: @Albin: I  just hoped SMB3 kept these. But if it's only Excel then it could be an add-on.

Comment: @harrymc addons might be worth checking...

Comment: See [Open Office apps in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72).

Comment: Although this problem occurs on Excel, it is still recommended to refer to "[An Office program is slow or may stop responding (hang) when you open a file from a network location](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/performance/office-slow-or-stop-responding)".

Comment: I have since tried all the suggestions here, no change, still a problem